# Unix calculator.bash having problems

Tags: bash, shell-script

This is a bash script I made to calculate numbers in Unix:

```
echo "Please enter the calculation(operation) type (+)(-)(*)(/)"
        read $opr
echo "Enter the first number"
        read $num1
echo "Enter the second number"
        read $num2
if [[ $opr = "+" ]]; then
        num=$(($num1 + $num2))
                echo "The sum is = $num"
elif [[ $opr = "-" ]]; then
        num=$(($num1 - $num2))
                echo "The sum is = $num"
elif [[ $opr = "*" ]]; then
        num=$(($num1 * $num2))
                echo "The sum is = $num"
elif [[ $opr = "/" ]]; then
        num=$(($num1 / $num2))
                echo "The sum is = $num"
fi
```

It runs, but it outputs "The sum is = ", and doesn't give a number.
Can you see anything that is causing this problem?

Comment: Run the script with `bash -x`.

Comment: You have no [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588). How are you running the script? And are you seeing any error output? Also, if you align the lines within the same context on the same line (i.e., put `read` and `echo` on the same lines as the preceding line) the script is going to be more readable.

Comment: Replace all `read $` by `read`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the current way you have of obtaining input via the `read` is wrong so the math is being done on nothing at all, so you end up with nothing for an answer. You simply have to fix this aspect and the rest of your code should work.

### How to read

An excerpt from your original posted code, shows that you were trying to save the first number like this:

```
echo "Enter the first number"
        read $num1
```

Instead, try using `-p` for the prompt and name the variable `num` without dollar sign. You can even test the following `read -p ...` on your command prompt, so you see:

```
$ read -p "Enter the first number" num1
Enter the first number:
```

Now enter 1:

```
$ read -p "Enter the first number" num1
Enter the first number: 1
```

Now if you were to `echo $num1`, you successfully see the value:

```
$ echo $num1
1
```

- `-p the_prompt_text` is a way to include a prompt
- compared with `echo`, `echo` appends a line return at the end. But since `-p` does not, it is a good idea to have an extra white-space like I have done, notice after the colon `:`, I have a space: `"Enter the first number: "`. This is just so the user's input does not appear run-on right against the colon.
- when specifying variables to save the response to, the correct syntax with read, is to not have the `$`, thus we had `read` and then `num1`

So with this, you should be able to adapt the `read` parts of your script and it would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

[user454038](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249126/80216) and [Cyrus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249118/unix-calculator-bash-having-problems#comment428693_249118) correctly described how to fix your problem,
but not what you're doing wrong. 
In the shell (or at least in bash) you use `$`
when you're referencing *the value of* a variable,
but not when you're referencing the variable itself
(i.e., when you're *setting* the value). 
This is confusing; in most (all?) normal programming languages,
you use the same syntax either way. 
You seem to understand this concept partially; you say

```
num=$(($num1 + $num2))
```

rather than making the common mistake of saying

```
$num=$(($num1 + $num2))                                                (Don't do this!)
```

This applies to the `read` statement, too. 
When you say `read $opr`, the `$opr` gets expanded
(i.e., replaced with the *current* value of the `opr` variable) —
and the current value of the `opr` variable is an empty string. 
So the command ends up looking like

```
read
```

And you might expect that to be an error;
in fact, it is equivalent to `read REPLY`.  So,

```
$ read $num1
17
$ echo $num1
                                                                    (Blank line output)
$ echo $REPLY
17
```

This example might illustrate the mechanism better:

```
$ superman=clark_kent
$ read $superman
man of steel
$ echo $superman
clark_kent
$ echo $clark_kent
man of steel
```

But you shouldn't do things like this (especially the above example)
because they are too cryptic;
readers/maintainers will have trouble understanding what the code is doing.

#### TL;DR

Your `read` statements should be `read opr`, `read num1`, and `read num2`
(without the `$`s).